# add an element to multidimensionnal array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr1[] = "Bob Marley";
$arr1[] = "Album1";
$arr1[][] = Song1;


  0 => string 'Bob Marley' 
  1 => string 'Album1'
  2 => 
      0 => string 'Song1'
```

I have the array above and want to add a new song in a loop, I want

```
      0 => string 'Bob Marley' 
      1 => string 'Album1'
      2 => 
          0 => string 'Song1' 
          1 => string 'Song2'
```

I have an array with albums (attr: name, artist, and an array of songs),  my code look like the following.

```
foreach ($AlbumsArray as $album) { 
        if(preg_match("#".$regexx."#i", $album->getArtist()) || preg_match("#".$regexx."#i", $album->getTitle())){
            $arrayAlbumFound[] = $album->getArtist();
            $arrayAlbumFound[] = $album->getTitle();
            $albumFound = true;
        }
        foreach ($album->getSongsArray() as $songs) {
            if(preg_match("#".$regexx."#i", $songs->getName())){
                if($albumFound){
                    $arrayAlbumFound[][count($arrayAlbumFound] = array($songs->getName()); 
                }
                else{ 
                    $arrayAlbumFound[] = $album->getArtist();
                    $arrayAlbumFound[] = $album->getTitle();
                    $arrayAlbumFound[count($arrayAlbumFound][] = $songs->getName(); 
                    $albumFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        $albumFound = false;
```

Comment: This isn't a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate variable for collecting the songs, and do it before storing the found album artist and title, so you know whether there are matching songs first:

```
foreach ($AlbumsArray as $album) { 
    $songsFound = [];
    foreach ($album->getSongsArray() as $songs) {
        if(preg_match("#".$regexx."#i", $songs->getName())){
            $songsFound[] = $songs->getName();
        }
    }
    if(count($songsFound) ||
            preg_match("#".$regexx."#i", $album->getArtist()) || 
            preg_match("#".$regexx."#i", $album->getTitle())){
        $arrayAlbumFound[] = $album->getArtist();
        $arrayAlbumFound[] = $album->getTitle();
        if (count($songsFound)) {
            $arrayAlbumFound[] = $songsFound;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is:

```
$arr1[] = "Bob Marley";
$arr1[] = "Album1"
$arr1[] = array('Song1', 'Song2', 'Song3');
```

More complicated is:

```
$arr1[] = "Bob Marley";    // element has index 0
$arr1[] = "Album1"         // element has index 1
// so next added element will have index `2`
$arr1[2][] = 'Song1';
$arr1[2][] = 'Song2';
$arr1[2][] = 'Song3';
```

Answer (score 0):

The value has to be an array itself, or you have to specify the key for the first dimension and use the new element [] operator on the second:

```
// with array value:
$arr1[] = "Bob Marley";
$arr1[] = "Album1";
$arr1[] = array("Song1");

// or with key:
$arr1[] = "Bob Marley";
$arr1[] = "Album1";
$arr1[2][] = "Song1'";
```

To get the highest key: `$arr1[count($arr1)][] = "Song1"`